# Code works fine as Java Application but throws NullPointerException on Server

Tags: java, jersey

This is my DataService Object.

```
public class DataService {

    private final String path = "src/main/resources/DataSource/data1.txt";

    private ArrayList<Person> _personList;
    private ArrayList<Course> _courseList;
    private QueryHandler _handler;

    public DataService() throws ParseException, JSONException, IOException {

        _personList = new ArrayList<>();
        _courseList = new ArrayList<>();
        String jsonData = Reader.readFile(path);

        JSONParser.read(jsonData, _courseList, _personList);

        _handler = new QueryHandler(_personList, _courseList);

    }
    public QueryHandler get_handler() {
        return _handler;
    }


}
```

When I call this in a Caller function, the following manner it works fine and returns the desired data.

```
public class Caller {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        DataService service = null;
        try {
            service = new DataService();
        } catch (JSONException | ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<Course> clist = service.get_handler().getAllCourses();


        clist.forEach(course -> System.out.println(course.toString()));

    }
}
```

Now however when I try calling it as a WebService , in this manner, it throws up a litany of errors.

```
@Path("/courses")
public class CourseService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public ArrayList<Course> getAllCourses(){
        DataService service = null;
        try {
            service = new DataService();
        } catch (JSONException | ParseException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return service.get_handler().getAllCourses();
    }
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting,

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    Service.CourseService.getAllCourses(CourseService.java:30)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

My project uses jersey to create a REST API. What am I doing wrong here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: And which is line 30 of `CourseService.java`?

Comment: BTW, I see no "litany of errors", just one stack trace.  Although they are verbose, stack traces are also very informative.

Comment: In any case, the value with which you initialize `DataService.path` looks very suspicious.  It is a *relative* path, and therefore dependent on the working directory, which is not necessarily what you think.  Indeed, it is conceivable that the target file is not even packaged into your webapp at all.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `return service.get_handler().getAllCourses();` that's line 30 of CourseService.java

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is this line:

```
private final String path = "src/main/resources/DataSource/data1.txt";
```

this works if you run the code in an IDE but not in an application server - because you don't actually have a src/main/resources folder there.

Try to load your txt file like this:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("DataSource/data1.txt");
```

Comment: So I used the following syntax, `String jsonData = Reader.readStream(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("DataSource/data1.txt"));` Now I get a blank page, no exceptions, but no data either.

Comment: what does Reader.readFile and JSONParser.read do?
have you checked if jsonData actually contains your file content?

Comment: I used the caller  class to check it that locally it works. But I'm not sure how can I check if the String jsonData actually contains the value. Reader.readStream read a JSON File into a string.

Comment: The service contains the handler object which has methods for all relvant queries and i've checked the data is their in the handler object.

Comment: so you say the data was properly loaded from the txt-file in your handler but your rest-service doesn't create the xml?

Comment: Yes infact now I checked using a JSON formate and all the JSON arrays are empty. But it shows the correct number of elements but the elements themselves are empty.

Comment: This has been driving me crazy for two days, do you want to take a look at the complete code.

Comment: sure, I think especially the Course class would be interesting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108001/discussion-between-ankur-and-kristian-ferkic).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that no previous exception was reported (i.e. via line 28 of `CourseService.java`), you could be confident that `service` was not `null` when execution reaches the line where the error occurs:

```
return service.get_handler().getAllCourses();
```

.  In that event, it would have to be the case that `service.get_handler()` returns `null`.  But `DataHandler.getService()` returns a value that is definitely set non-null by the `DataHandler` constructor if it completes successfully, and that value is not modified after.

We must therefore conclude that the `DataService` constructor is failing, and the resulting exception is caught in the provided `catch` block.  The stack trace that you print as a result would probably be illuminating, but you have not presented it.  Possibly it's going to a different output stream than the one where the stack trace you presented is sent.

I observe at this point that your handling of such an exception is flawed.  If you fail to instantiate a `DataService` then your method cannot continue successfully, so it is inappropriate to catch the exception and just continue.  If you don't want to declare all the possible exceptions, then you could instead define one custom exception type with which to wrap (and throw) such exceptions, or else you could use a `ServletException` for that purpose.

As to why the constructor might be failing, I reiterate my observation from comments:

> the value with which you initialize DataService.path looks very suspicious.  It is a relative path, and therefore dependent on the working directory, which is not necessarily what you think. Indeed, it is conceivable that the target file is not even packaged into your webapp at all.

Rather than opening a file, you might have better luck ensuring that the wanted file is packaged some place that you can be certain will be in the webapp's classpath, and using the context `ClassLoader`'s `getResourceAsStream()` method to get an `InputStream` from which to read its contents.  Among other things, this will work even if your WAR is not exploded when it is deployed, and it does not depend on the server's working directory to find the data file.  Alternatively, if you're supposed to be accessing an *external* file, then make its (absolute) path a context parameter, and obtain the path that way instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: I changed my annotation to `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` and I get the following output` [{},{},{}]`. The array is indeed supposed to have 3 elements. So the array is there just the elements are not showing up. I'm lost.

Comment: @Ankur, it is very difficult to credit your assertion that changing the parameter of the `@Produces` annotation is sufficient to change the behavior of your webapp from throwing an NPE to successfully returning a response, even a wrong one.  You would increase the likelihood of receiving an accurate diagnosis by presenting an [mcve].

Comment: @Ankur, with that said, it is unclear to me whether JavaEE should be expected to do anything useful with a service method that returns an `ArrayList<Course>`.  What you have presented does not exhibit why that would be so.  I am inclined to believe that you have solved your original problem -- perhaps by accident -- and that the incorrect response is an altogether separate one.  In that case, it ought to be posed separately.